# Politely ask to finish my points in conversations

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, meetings

My style when I talk in meetings is a modest pace of speaking and trying to explain a specific point.
I occasionally run into some people which have the habit of interrupting me in the middle of a sentence and start talking an argument really really fast.
When I manage to speak again (after patiently waiting the other to finish his speech) most of the times I manage to convince them but it requires of me too much effort and time due to the difference in styles. Because of the difference in speaking speed the other has made so much wrong statements that I need to correct that's it's just too much time and effort.
How can I politely stop someone from derailing the conversation like that and allowing to finish my sentences?

Comment: @GrayCygnus: they don't stop me while I am talking they stop me right when inhaling in the middle of a sentence which is obvious I am not done in case it makes a difference

Comment: I see, then I consider you should look at the question linked as they mention things like that in it.

Comment: Consider both sides: Other people's attention/time is as much a resource as your flow of thought; be respectful of that. Maybe your explanations may be long-winded. Having little time, I work hard to keep my points short and to the point to not waste other people's time (unless it's more a "socialising" conversation rather than a conversation to convey information). Some people argue that their arguments must be long to be full and complete - if this were true, this would require a dedicated meeting, even if for 20 minutes. If not the latter, the argument can made to be snappy.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: that's a solid argument actually. Thank you.

Comment: Especially pay attention to what @PurpleVermont answered.

Comment: @HLGEM: won't that sentence sound defensive and take the conversation to a different track i.e. confrontational?

Comment: It will sound assertive not defensive. And yes it will take the conversation on a different track, one where you are taken seriously and not interrupted. That is the whole point.Letting people walk all over you by interrupting you is a career killer.